# Compare two files headers and make sure they have the same headers regardless of order

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to compare two configuration files, one a user generated one and the other the template.

I have the code working but feel there is a much better way to deal with this.

```
#config variable designated previously

current.config.template<-'/location/of/template'
default.config<- read.csv(current.config.template,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

bool<-colnames(default.config) %in% colnames(config)

for(i in bool){
  if(i==FALSE){
    stop("Please use the most recent met-ingest.csv file located /path/to/file/")
  }
}
```

It works, but I feel there has to be a better way to to this rather than an if loop within a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop. You can simply do this -

```
if(any(!bool)) {
    stop("Please use the most recent met-ingest.csv file located /path/to/file/")
}
```

Comment: Much more concise, would it be recommended to skip the "bool" variable creation and just place the %in% portion of it into the any() function?

Comment: @twseewx it's a matter of personal preference. Just do whatever is more comfortable to you.